# Not pushing / Committing changes

Tags: git, github

I am trying to Push/Commit a changes to a repository but on Github and I keep getting the error:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

Even when I have updated the files in the repository. I have tried:

```
git push

git push -f

git add "filename"
```

But none of of these commands seem to be updating the repository (when I check online). Does anyone know why, or, have any suggestions to what I can use?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: By default, `git push` pushes to the `origin` remote -- is your github remote `origin`? Try `git remote -v` to see the list of remotes

Comment: @fge I get "orign git@github.com:myusername/testing-server.git (fetch) orign git@github.com:myusername/testing-server.git (push)" is this normal?

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. Are you sure you push to the correct branch etc?

Comment: Did you commit those files? Do you see the commit after typing `git log`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all

> Everything up-to-date

is not really an error, it's more a everything-is-ok message :)

The workflow with git is like - assuming you already done the `git init`:

1. Add/edit files in your local repo
2. `git add filename` to warn git that you add some new files
3. Then `git commit -m filename` to commit your change, the -m is for message. git will ask you what is the commit message.
4. When ALL this steps are done, well you can make many commit before pushing, but, when your done `git push origin` will send all your modification to the server.

Here is a [link](http://www.git-scm.com/book) for a complete manual about git workflow

Comment: That worked!! However, do I have to do these steps all the time? Even if I update a file in the repository with just 1 line? The reason I'm asking is: (I don't want to use Github as a back-up) but I would like to create a crontab that push's the repository at midnight every friday.. But, if I add a file - this wouldn't be possible, right?

Comment: Yon don't have to push for every modification but you must commit yes. It's the way git works.
N.B : If you want to use another server as 'backup' you can maybe consider to have a look into hooks, which can deploy from the server to Github for you :)

Comment: Thanks :) I've got this to work now, it's not the best solution - but it will work until I can get around to reading more into Git.